# Definition of subspace spanned by columns of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I'm learning some linear algebra before my exams, and I'm trying to get my vocabulary straight.

I have an exercise which goes as following

> Does $u$ lie in the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ spanned by the columns of $A$.

Given that $u = \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ -3 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$
and $A = \begin{bmatrix}5 & 8 & 7 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 3 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Now I'm trying to understand the part of subspace, and why it says subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ instead of any other dimension. Is it because the matrix $A$ span is reaching into the third dimension? So by `subspace`, does it mean its not required to reach `ALL` points of $\mathbb{R}^3$, but at least $1$.

If thats the case, what if matrix $A$ was defined as

$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

would it still be subspace?

And if not would $u$ in this case lie in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and not the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is an operator from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m.$ The subspace spanned by a matrix is just the range of values that it attains, that is,

$$S= \{Ax:x\in \mathbb{R}^n\}.$$(Note that this set is actually a subspace) Hence, if you want to know whether the vector $u$ lies in the subspace spanned by the matrix $A,$ you just have to check whether the system

$$Ax=u$$ has a solution.

Comment: However, is there a reason why we call it `subspace` instead of just saying the third dimension? Is it related to the points of which the matrix spans?

Comment: I turns out that not always $S= \mathbb{R}^m.$  This only happens iff  $rank(A)= n,$ or equivalently, the columns of $A$ are linearly independent. Hence in general $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ strictly, and o we the concept of subspace is needed

Comment: You able to dumb it down for me a bit? Still confused, haha. Is it correct to think of subspace as a smaller part of the dimension its in, but not all of it?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: whenever we reference a subspace, do we reference the space which a specific matrix spans, which is not ALWAYS the entire parenting space? or do we simply reference amount of rows/columns in the matrix? Example: I have $\mathbb{R}^3$, is the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ all or just parts of the entire $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: you can reference a subspace by giving a basis of it. For example: The subspace spanned by $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ is $$S=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in \mathbb{R}^3: x_3=0\}$$ Does that clears your doubt?

Comment: ahhh, yeah I think so. Let me just see if I get it. If we did not allow the point $(0,0,0)$ for some reason. Then the subspace would be $\mathbb{R}^2$ since no points would lie on any value on the "z-axis"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62911/discussion-between-magnusseen-and-phycomath).

Answer (score 1):

A matrix $M = \begin{bmatrix}a&d&g\\b&e&h\\c&f&i\end{bmatrix}$ transforms $3$-dimensional basis vectors $\hat i, \hat j, \hat k$ into new basis vectors, at positions $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}d\\e\\f\end{bmatrix}$, and $\begin{bmatrix}g\\h\\i\end{bmatrix}$ respectively.

Let's say we have arbitrary vector $x\hat i + y\hat j + z\hat k$. When you do matrix-vector multiplication, the resultant vector can be described in terms of the new basis vectors, $x\cdot (a\hat i + b\hat j + c\hat k) + y\cdot (a\hat i + b\hat j + c\hat k) + z\cdot (g\hat i + h\hat j + i\hat k)$.

The columns of the matrix span $\mathbb{R}^3$ because the new basis vectors span $\mathbb{R}^3$.

However, this is not the case when not all columns of the matrix are linearly independent. There is degeneracy in the transformed basis vectors, so the span is less than $3$-dimensional.

So the identity matrix is in $\mathbb{R}^3$, because it doesn't transform the basis vectors, and the basis vectors span the entire space.

See 3blue1brown's Introduction to Linear Algebra, and all the best for your test!

Comment: I've watched parts of the Linear Algebra course by 3blue1brown, its great :) Just curious to get a intuitive sense of subspace, and why we use it, instead of just referencing to for example the third, or fourth dimension.

Comment: You should watch the entire thing. It'll for sure help in the test!